# How can I end the display of passes as soon as the elements are all sorted in proper order in bubble sort c++?

Tags: c++, optimization, bubble-sort

This is my whole code:

```
void bubbleAsc(int arr[], int arraySize)
{
int i, j, temp, flag=1; 
                
for(i=0; (i<arraySize-1) && flag; i++)
{
    flag= 0;
    for(j=0; j<(arraySize-i-1); j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
        {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;

            flag = 1; 
        }
    }

    cout<<"\n\nPass "<<i+1<<": ";
    for(j=0; (j<arraySize); j++)
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

}
}

main Bubble()
{
   int i, arraySize, arr[50];

cout<<"Bubble Sort Algorithm"<<endl;
cout<<"\nEnter the array size: ";
cin>>arraySize;

cout<<endl;
cout<<"Enter "<<arraySize <<" numbers: "<<endl;

for(i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
    cin>>arr[i];

        bubbleAsc(arr, arraySize);

        cout<<"\n\nThe New Sorted Array in Ascending Order: \n";
            for(i=0; i<arraySize; i++)
                cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
                cout<<endl;
    }
return 0;

}
```

Here is the line of codes where the display of passes is being done:

```
cout<<"\n\nPass "<<i+1<<": ";
for(j=0; (j<arraySize); j++)
    cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
cout<<endl;
```

I tried entering 5 numbers, specifically {5,1,2,3,4} then this is the result:

Array before Sorting:
5 1 2 3 4

Pass 1: 1 2 3 4 5

Pass 2: 1 2 3 4 5

The New Sorted Array in Ascending Order:
1 2 3 4 5

What I want is for the display of passes to stop when the elements are already in sorted order. In this case, after Pass 1, there should be no Pass 2 anymore because it is just the same as Pass 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code correctly stops sorting as soon as the array is sorted.

But the printout is done twice because you are not checking `flag` beforehand:

```
    cout<<"\n\nPass "<<i+1<<": ";
    for(j=0; (j<arraySize); j++)
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
```

You should condition that with `if (flag)`.

Or even better, use a flag inside the loop and not outside of it:

```
for(int i=0; i<arraySize-1; i++)
{
    bool stop = true;
    for(int j=0; j<arraySize-i-1; j++)
    {
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
        {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;

            stop = false;
        }
    }
    if (stop)
        break;

    cout<<"\n\nPass "<<i+1<<": ";
    for(int j=0; j<arraySize; j++)
        cout<<arr[j]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: you should show the corrected code

Comment: I get it now and it is working. Thanks